# text field in jTable something better than ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)!

Tags: java, swing, jtable, textfield

hi guys hope you all well.. to day i have a question again i am using a text field in jTable to edit a column and i use 
`model.getValueAt();` from a column and `model.setValueAt();` to another column after doing some calculations fanaly when i press enter key the action replays but sometimes does not reply and does not update changing so i have to press again...  my code looks something like this:

```
private void txt_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
 try {
        int viewRow = table.getSelectedRow();
        String id = (table.getModel().getValueAt(viewRow, 1).toString());

        String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable_1 where ID1='"+id1+"'";
        dm.pst = dm.c.prepareStatement(sql1);
        dm.rs = dm.pst.executeQuery();
        if (dm.rs.next()) {
        float a = dm.rs.getFloat("mycolumn_1");
        float b = Float.parseFloat(model.getValueAt(viewRow, model.getColumnCount()-10).toString());
        float c = Float.parseFloat(model.getValueAt(viewRow, model.getColumnCount()-9).toString());
        String d = model.getValueAt(viewRow, model.getColumnCount()-8).toString();

        float e = 0;
        switch (d) {
            case "U":case "1":e = 0;break;
            case "W":case "2":e = 7;break;
            case "X":case "3":e = 10;break;
            case "Y":case "4":e = 14;break;
            case "Z":case "5":e = 20;break;
            default:System.err.println("Error..");break;
        }
        if(b>a){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "B is Bigger than A..!!");
        }else if(a>=b){

          float val_1 = a-b
          float val_2 = b * c;
          float val_3 = b * (((e / 100) + 1) * c);
        model.setValueAt(val_3, viewRow, model.getColumnCount()-6); 
        model.setValueAt(val_2, viewRow, model.getColumnCount()-7); 
        model.setValueAt(val_1, viewRow, model.getColumnCount()-11); 
        String id2 = (table.getModel().getValueAt(viewRow, 0).toString());
        String upid = "update mydb.mytable_2 set mycolumn_2='" + b + "'where ID2='" + id2 + "'";
        dm.pst = dm.c.prepareStatement(upid);
        dm.pst.execute();
        }
    }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
```

}

anything else better than action performed?
Note: after i edited my code i would say that i am using `JTextField txt_ = new JTextField();` as an editor for my column and i am using `model = new DefaultTableModel()`
thank in advance

Comment: You're asking a question about a complex set of processes and describing an intermittent bug, meaning that this is likely a complex bug. My guess is that we're not going to be able to understand your problem or your code well without your posting a well-crafted [mcve]. This is not a full code dump or a link to code, but rather a new separate **small** program that you create and post here with your question (again not a link), that we can copy and paste, and compile and run and that tries to demonstrate your problem for us. Please read the [mcve] link for the details on this useful tool.

Comment: ok i will update my code

Comment: there is no problem in my code i am just looking for something better than action performed that i am to listener thank you :-)

Comment: Well, camickr has given you an excellent option.

Comment: yeah it is worked fine now as i expected ;-)

Comment: Good deal. He is one very smart programmer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101870/discussion-between-anti-atlas-dev-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i am using a text field in jTable to edit a column and i use model.getValueAt(); from a column and model.setValueAt(); to another column

Don't use an ActionListener.

Your logic should be defined in your TableModel

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column)
{
    super.setValueAt(...);

    if (column == ?)
        //  add logic here to do calculation and update other column value
}
```

Comment: should i override getValueAt method as well please more explanation according to my code that i posted

Comment: @AntiAtlasDev Start by having a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and the JavaDocs for [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) and [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) to further understand how the API works. I'd also be surprised if anyone can add more information based on the out-of-context code snippt you've provided